# SQLAlchemy Example Projects

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Are there any good example projects which uses SQLAlchemy (with Python Classes) that I can look into? (which has at least some basic database operations - CRUD)

I believe that, it is a good way to learn any programming language by looking into someone's code.

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/search?q=from+sqlalchemy&type=Everything&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1

Comment: consider the examples that come with sqlalchemy: https://bitbucket.org/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/src/tip/examples

Answer (score 4):

My [Flask-Security-Admin-Example](https://github.com/sasaporta/flask-security-admin-example) project might help. It uses SQLAlchemy ORM in a Python Flask web application that also integrates Flask-Security and Flask-Admin.

Also, although it's not a project, the [SQLAlchemy ORM tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html) is quite good, and walks you through writing the code you would need in a SQLAlchemy project.

Note that both of the above examples use SQLAlchemy ORM. If you don't want an object relational mapper, you can use [SQLAlchemy Core](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/). I don't have a project that illustrates that, though.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of environment are you looking to work with on top of SQLAlchemy?

Most likely, if you are using a popular web framework like django, Flask or Pylons, you can find many  examples and tutorials specific to that framework that include SQLAlchemy.

This will boost your knowledge both with SQLAlchemy and whatever else it is you are working with.

Chances are, you won't find any good project examples in 'just' SQLAlchemy as it essentially a tool.